# iPhone - Trying to Display 2 different object types in a table-view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I'm using to try and display 2 different objects - receipts and milages.

This is the original code I was using to try and accomplish this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    Project *project = [[Project alloc] init];
    project = [appDelegate.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.row >= [project.receipts count])
    {
        if (indexPath.row >= [project.milages count]){
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            //Create a new journey cell and set its UI values
            MilageCell *cell = (MilageCell *)[tableView 
                                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MilageCell"];
            Milage *milage = [project.milages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.locationLabel.text = milage.location;
            cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", milage.date];
            cell.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", milage.total];
            return cell;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ReceiptCell *cell = (ReceiptCell *)[tableView 
                                            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReceiptCell"];
        Receipt *receipt = [project.receipts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.dateLabel.text = receipt.receiptDate;
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = receipt.descriptionNote;
        cell.amountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", receipt.amount];
        return cell;
    }

}
```

I'm aware that if I have 1 object in each of the arrays (project.receipts and project.milages) then this code won't work at all.  I also know you can't return NULL from this method.  What I'm trying to do is somehow display all my receipt objects, then all my milage objects (so say  section 0 in the table view had 3 receipts and 3 milages, it would firstly display the receipts, then the milages).  However I have absolutely no idea how to do this, can someone explain how I might solve this problem?  Is there some way I could construct a single array of all the milage and receipt objects and then somehow discern which what kind of object I have in this method in order to use the appropriate cell type?

Thanks a lot,

Jack

Comment: Why do you first `init` your project and then overwrite it? Firstly it doesn't make any sense, and secondly, you are leaking memory: `Project *project = [[Project alloc] init];
    project = [appDelegate.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've just removed an if condition and subtracted the `[project.milages count]` from the `index.row` for the Receipt cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    Project *project = [[Project alloc] init];
    project = [appDelegate.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        if (indexPath.row >= [project.milages count]){
            ReceiptCell *cell = (ReceiptCell *)[tableView 
                                                dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReceiptCell"];
            Receipt *receipt = [project.receipts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-[project.milages count]];
            cell.dateLabel.text = receipt.receiptDate;
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = receipt.descriptionNote;
            cell.amountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", receipt.amount];
            return cell;
        }
        else {
            //Create a new journey cell and set its UI values
            MilageCell *cell = (MilageCell *)[tableView 
                                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MilageCell"];
            Milage *milage = [project.milages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.locationLabel.text = milage.location;
            cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", milage.date];
            cell.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", milage.total];
            return cell;
        }
}
```

You can also use an `UITableView` with two different sections.